# Accessing a list with objects outside form

Tags: c#

I have a form where I have a list with objects stored. I then have a dialog in which I wish to access this list and loop through its content.

The main form:

```
namespace personregister
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }      

    public List<person> personStorage = new List<person>();
```

In the dialogue I want to do something like this:

```
namespace personregister
{
public partial class AddPersonDialogue : Form
{
    public AddPersondialogue()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        foreach (person p in personStorage)
        {
          //do stuff
        }
    }
```

problem is that I cannot access personStorage which I created in the other form. How do I access that list in the dialogue window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a method to do the dialoge and call after it is constructed.

```
public partial class AddPersonDialogue : Form
{
    public AddPersonDialogue()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            

    }

    public void SetUpPeople(List<person> personStorage)
    {
        foreach (person p in personStorage)
        {
          //do stuff
        }
    }
}

 public Form1()
 {
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }      

    public List<person> personStorage = new List<person>();

    public void ShowForm()
    {
        var dialogue = new AddPersonDialogue();

        dialogue.SetUpPeople(personStorage);

        dialogue.Show();
    }
}
```

You could also do it via the constructor.

```
public partial class AddPersonDialogue : Form
{
    public AddPersonDialogue(List<person> personStorage)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (person p in personStorage)
        {
          //do stuff
        }       

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Now that you're renamed your function to show that it's a constructor- option #1 below is best.  Just add `IList<person> personStorage` as a parameter to your constructor. (or `IEnumeable<person> personStorage` to make it more versatile if you don't need list-specific functionality)

---

Since `AddPersonDialogue` does not know anything about `Form1` it does not know how to get `personStorage`.  Assuming you are creating the dialog from within `Form1` here are a few options:

1. Add a constructor to `AddPersonDialogue` that takes a `List<person>` parameter and assign that value to a property.  That way you can access it within `AddPersonDialogue`.
2. Add a public property to `AddPersonDialogue` for `PersonStorage`.  Then set that property after you create the dialog.

If the list is essential for the form to run I'd put it in the constructor so that and caller will know that it is a required component.